# Line breaks in a seed data string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am building a website for a client where I need to be able to put line breaks into some text in the seed data. 
This is not rendering in the page.

For instance, if the seed data = "some text some text some text `<br>`some text some text some text `<br>` some text some text some text..."
i would like it to display as:

```
"some text some text some text

some text some text some text

some text some text some text..."
```

Instead it shows the text with the `<br>`tags written in and no line-spacing.

It is not written in html, it is pulled from the database. I would like it to be easy to write, as the client needs to be able to edit the text in rails admin...

Answer (score 5):

Old post but I just found that `seeds.rb` will respect `\n` when you use double quotes but not when you use single.

eg.

```
"\n"    # works
'\n'    # doesn't work
```

Comment: finally, I get the simple answer, thank

Answer (score 1):

Try to use end line character \n.

Comment: also does not render unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Seed the content with actual line breaks in your file. For example:

```
Animal.create({name: 'Jackalope', description: 'Jackalopes are the best.

Too bad they don\'t exist.'})
```

When pulling this record from the DB and passing it to `simple_format`, it will generate`<br>` tags for single line breaks, and `<p>` tags for double line-breaks (like the one I have in my example).

If you have already seeded your DB and don't want to erase it, you can update all the necessary values in a new seed with code like:

```
Animal.all.each do |animal|
    animal.description = animal.description.gsub! '\n', '
'
    animal.save
end
```

I just did this 5min ago so I can confirm that it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you are rendering text with HTML tags use .html_safe

```
"some text <br>some text<br>some text".html_safe
```

Answer (score 0):

For example in Laravel Seeder

`'height' => 'od 1,2m do 2m',`
We must do
`'height' => 'od 1,2m'."\n".'do 2m',`
**And everything is Ok now !**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).